# aligning Jframe to different locations

Tags: java, jframe, desktop-application

i know that java being run on JVM makes it platform independent . i was recently learning to develop desktop apps so my question is: how to make my appscreen pop at the exactly top right/left or bottom right/left or centre? like, for top right we can simply use :
`frame.setLocation(0,0)`
or for the centre, one good , platform independent way i found here was:
`frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)`

but what about the other 3 edges? i saw some big chunks of code using other  classes (the dimensions/point class) or packages but either they were too complex or a perticular direction oriented(like one answer here i saw will easily make my app popup at the bottom; but if my teacher said he wants to see the app popup on top, i have to recode my entire solution).i also tried using `getmaximumsize().height/width` but to no good.

i wish if someone could assist me with a code handling all the possible edges and centre location(even if it uses other classes/packages;as long as it satisfies all the above cases,your answer is welcome). and another mini-question: are  there any variables `MAXWINDOW` in java like , my window screen is 15.6" and the 0.5" toolbar below makes the ideal bottom for my 250*100 pixel jframe to be 0,15.5" , a variable telling that perticular ideal value? and changing its value according to location of my toolbar or operating systems having smaller/bigger sizes and toolbar locations??
it just came in mind because it felt like a variable like this  could be quite handy and adds more to the platform-independency nature of java.

**EDIT**...
thanks to both @bjorn and @madprogrammer for their too good answers. i never thought that "getting taskbar-free window size for location" problem will need such a big code considering the platform independent clause. i feel bjorn's answer currently satisfies me completely. but mad's answer is more accurate(or precise?ugh my English) to the problems i quoted .

Comment: *"i can even use this snippet for getting a max sized window "* - I would look at `JFrame#setExtendedState` and maximise the window in a platform independent way which won't place parts of the window beneath the taskbar/dock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` returns the full screen size of the **default** screen, it doesn't take into consideration other screen elements like the dock or taskbar, which aren't always at the bottom of the screen and aren't always the same size

A better solution might be to make use of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets` and `GraphicsConfiguration`

```
public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(Window window) {
    return getScreenViewableBounds((Component) window);
}

public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(Component comp) {
    return getScreenViewableBounds(getGraphicsDevice(comp));
}

public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(GraphicsDevice gd) {
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (gd == null) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    if (gd != null) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        bounds = gc.getBounds();

        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
        bounds.x += insets.left;
        bounds.y += insets.top;
        bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
        bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    }

    return bounds;
}
```

This will return the "safe viewable" range of a specific screen. If you pass it `null`, it will use the "default" screen

```
// Safe viewable area for default screen
Rectangle bounds = getScreenViewableBounds(null);
int x = bounds.x + ((bounds.width - getWidth());
int y = bounds.y + ((bounds.width - getHeight());

setLocation(x, y);
```

Which would place the window in the bottom/right hand position of the window, BUT, place it aligned to the taskbar (because most people have it aligned along the bottom)

For weird people, like me, who place the taskbar at the top of the screen

```
// Safe viewable area for default screen
Rectangle bounds = getScreenViewableBounds(null);
int x = bounds.x;
int y = bounds.y;

setLocation(x, y);
```

will place the window at the top/left corner of the viewable, aligned below the the taskbar

And yes, I've seen too many developers use `setLocation(0, 0)` and place the window under the taskbar/menu bar, their names become "mud"

Comment: thankyou for such an in depth answer!you have coded a solution to exactly the problem i was thinking about.although now i see the answer, i think the problem i quoted is somewhat more nasty xD . will definately come back to this solution when i have enough knowledge to understand it as whole.(am a bit noob,y'know :p)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the screen's size with the following code:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

In you frame you can then set the according position by subtracting the JFrame's width from the screen's width. For the height it's the same procedure accordingly.

Comment: thankyou!, i can even use this snippet for getting a max sized window :)

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration such elements like the dock or task bar and runs the risk of placing the window beneath them

Comment: @anshsachdeva: That's not a good idea. You should better call [JFrame.setExtendedState(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int))

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right. I thought "pop at the exactly top right/left or bottom right/left" was referring to the screen's edges, not the accessible desktop.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar The number of windows that open under my taskbar infuriates me :P

Comment: @Björn,@mad just checked the setExtened() oracle link. thanks again. :).